# Bash pass argument for array selection

Tags: bash

I'm trying to pass the second argument to get an array and loop trough but im getting this error: `${$2[@]}: bad substitution`

my code is:

/etc/init.d/displaycameras start c1

```
    #!/bin/bash
    dis1cam1="screen -dmS dis1cam1 sh -c 'omxplayer --avdict rtsp_transport:tcp --win \"0 0 640 428\" rtsp://myvideo --live -n -1'";
    camera_feeds=('c1=(dis1cam1 dis1cam2 dis1cam3 dis1cam4 dis1cam5 dis1cam6 dis1cam8 dis1cam9)' 'c2=(dis2cam1 dis2cam2 dis2cam3 dis2cam4)')
    for elt in "${camera_feeds[@]}";do eval $elt;done

    # Start displaying camera feeds
    case "$1" in
    start)
    for i in "${$2[@]}"
    do
    eval eval '$'$i
    done
    echo "Camera Display 1 Started"
    ;;
```

Is there a way to pass the 2nd argument to call the c2 set ?

in this way is working perfect:

```
        #!/bin/bash
 dis1cam1="screen -dmS dis1cam1 sh -c 'omxplayer --avdict rtsp_transport:tcp --win \"0 0 640 428\" rtsp://myvideo --live -n -1'";

        camera_feeds=('c1=(dis1cam1 dis1cam2 dis1cam3 dis1cam4 dis1cam5 dis1cam6 dis1cam8 dis1cam9)' 'c2=(dis2cam1 dis2cam2 dis2cam3 dis2cam4)')
        for elt in "${camera_feeds[@]}";do eval $elt;done

        # Start displaying camera feeds
        case "$1" in
        start)
        for i in "${c1[@]}"
        do
        eval eval '$'$i
        done
        echo "Camera Display 1 Started"
        ;;
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use all the `eval` here?

Comment: Is to sanitize the multidimensional array and when i call  "${c1[@]}" or "${c2[@]}" it will do the for loop, the eval is to start the service on omxplayer

Comment: Which **exact** version of bash is targeted? (4.3 provides a much better way of doing this).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the Bash version is 4.3.30(1)-release

Comment: I can separate the multidimensional array, but what i need is to invoke the array set in the for loop from argument

Comment: Good, then -- my answer should work. And you'll note there's no `eval` anywhere in it.

Comment: Yes, my answer *is* iterating over both arrays in turn. Try it.

Comment: (though... are you storing *code* in a variable named `dis1cam3`? Don't do that -- [there are better alternatives](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)).

Comment: Note also that `init` scripts won't typically get called with the arguments you show in your example... they will typically be called with just `start` or `stop`.

Comment: Don't add an answer to your question -- if you want to add your own answer, you can do that with the "add an answer" button. (Accepting your own answer is perfectly acceptable, if no 3rd-party answer solved your problem).

Comment: ...if you put an answer *in the question itself*, however, that means that the question and the answer are inseparable -- one can't upvote or downvote the question without doing so to the question as well, can't comment on them individually, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I just added the part of the code is working perfectly, my problem is that i need to declare if c1 or c2 need to pass trough loop, but i got the error of bad substitution and thats why i asked if is there a way to set c1 or c2 as variable and pass to the loop

Comment: That's too vague to be actionable -- in part because this isn't a [mcve]: I can't copy-and-paste your code and see the same error you're reporting (and, likewise, there's no expected correct output given to compare a proposed answer against).

Comment: not all people has omxplayer installed to run the code, the idea is to start each camera from a set, but i need to say you c1 start or you c2 start, this is because the number of cameras is too big and i need to make a rotation.

Comment: @ndAR, my point is that you can (should) generate a **minimal** example that doesn't *need* "omxplayer" installed, to let people test their work Again, see the page on building a [mcve] in the StackOverflow Help Center.

Answer (score 2):

I would **strongly** advise implementing this differently.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

die() { echo "$*" >&2; exit 1; }
[[ $BASH_VERSION = [0-3]* ]] && die "Bash 4.3 or newer needed"
[[ $BASH_VERSION = 4.[0-2].* ]] && die "Bash 4.3 or newer needed"

dis1cam1() { : "code to start camera dis1cam1 here"; )
dis1cam2() { : "code to start camera dis1cam2 here"; )
# ...etc...

camera_feeds__c1=(dis1cam1 dis1cam2 dis1cam3 dis1cam4 dis1cam5 dis1cam6 dis1cam8 dis1cam9)
camera_feeds__c2=(dis2cam1 dis2cam2 dis2cam3 dis2cam4)

# here, we're showing the iterate-over-all-feeds case
# you can just set var=camera_feeds__c1 yourself if you prefer
for var in "${!camera_feeds__@}"; do  # var will be camera_feeds__c1 or camera_feeds__c2
  feed_name=${var#camera_feeds__}     # feed_name will be "c1" or "c2"
  declare -n camera_feeds=$var
  for i in "${camera_feeds[@]}"; do
    echo "Starting $i in feed $feed_name" >&2
    "$i" # look up and run code in variable named in $i
  done
  unset -n camera_feeds
done
```

- `"${camera_feeds__@}"` expands to the list of shell variables whose names start with `camera_feeds__`; this is thus the name of our two arrays.
- `declare -n camera_feeds=$var` then makes `camera_feeds` an alias for the array presently being iterated over, such that `for i in "${camera_feeds[@]}"` iterates over that array.
- `unset -n camera_feeds` clears this association.

Comment: No, is not good this way because i need to invoke wich one  to start.

Comment: So? Then take the name from your argument list instead of from the results of iterating over the full set of variables. The technique of using namerefs is what's important here; if you use `var="camera_feeds__$2"` instead of a `for` loop, that makes little difference.

Comment: The idea with this script is to start a screen randomly or by command in argument, so first set of cams will stop and next will start, what you do is to start the entire set, and is not fine as i need to declare wich set to start.

Comment: Sure, but the technique I'm showing to iterate over an array named in a variable **is completely separable** from that. Take the part you want, discard the part you don't.

Comment: @ndAR, ...and the other thing -- and it's important -- is that your objections are all based on details you didn't include in the question, meaning that they aren't based on things that make the answer nonresponsive. It's not my problem that you asked a vague question that doesn't reflect what you actually want to do.

Comment: No Charles, the version you give me is more beautiful, it returns dis2cam1: command not found because try to pas on each variable from c1 and c2, i just need to say c1 or c2 but from argument, im not really good explaining but i think the best way is to ask how can i pass a variable to ${$myvariable[@]} ?

Comment: @ndAR, and the answer is `declare -n ref=$myvariable`, and then use `${ref[@]}`, and `unset -n ref` afterwards -- which is what the code above does.

Comment: @ndAR, ...I had to guess at what `dis1cam1` actually is (a command to be run, a variable, etc), since you didn't define it anywhere in your question except as a value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147721/discussion-between-ndar-and-charles-duffy).